# ui-select is not visible

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I try use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) instead select in Angular app. My problem is that ui-select is not visible.

This is working code with select:

```
    <select class = "form-control"
            ng-model = "vm.user">
        <option ng:repeat = "u in vm.users"
                value = "{{u.id}}">
            {{u.login}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

not working code with ui-select

```
   <ui-select  ng-model = "vm.user"
               style = "width: 300px; height: 50px">
        <ui-select-choices repeat = "u in vm.users">
            <div ng-bind-html = "u.login"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

**index.html**

```
    <!-- UI-Select -->
    <link href = "content/select.min.css"
          rel = "stylesheet" />
    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src = "scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- UI-Select -->
    <script src="scripts/select.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Did you add the ui-select module as a dependancy for your app ? I'd guess not.

Comment: @ Pierre Gayvallet: no, I forgot, please post answer I will accept it...thank you

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the **ui-select-match** directive as well. otherwise it will not be displayed.

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="do select..">
  {{$select.selected.login}}
</ui-select-match>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do:

- add dependency:

```js
angular.module('something', ['ui.select'])
```

- use code like this:

```html
<ui-select ng-model="vm.user" style="width: 300px; height: 50px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select user...">
        {{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="user in vm.users | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="user.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

- I assume that ui-select is not visible for you. If you don't see a dropdown then it could be caused by one of the following issue:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1731

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1652